# Power generation by extracting heat from the environment?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, heat-engine

It is chilly outside now and I am kept warm by a heat pump with [COP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_performance) 5.5: eating only 0.6 kW, it steals 2.6 kW from the outside air (making it even colder) and delivers the resulting 3.2 kW into my house.

Which makes me wonder: why isn't it practicable to generate electricity by drawing thermal energy from the environment? Do the laws of physics prevent the heat that heat pumps deliver from being used for electricity generation by whatever means (e.g. steam turbine)?

Comment: It's the poor efficiency of the combined processes involved.

Comment: @SolarMike are you saying there are still no ways to make > 0.6 kW of electricity out of 3.2 kW of heat?

Comment: Sure it's practical, that's what solar panels are. For these, the "environment" is effectively the surface of the Sun. You need a large temperature difference for this to be useful.

Comment: The amount of work it takes to pump the heat from the cold environment to the hotter environment would be exactly the same as the amount of work you could get from using that heat to generate the work in a heat engine operating between the same two temperatures.  So the net effect would be zero.

Comment: @Greendrake See the latest revisions to my answer.

Comment: @knzhou Solar panels work using the photoelectric effect.  Can you elaborate on how the temperature of the surface of the sun matters for that?

Comment: @JimmyJames From a thermodynamic point of view the important thing is that the Sun is an object of a certain temperature, and hence the radiation it gives out has that temperature too. And thermodynamic bounds apply no matter how you capture the energy.

Comment: @knzhou I believe it's possible to have a set up with a halogen bulb and an array of LEDs that produce the same amount of energy a small solar panel where the temperatures of the two light sources are quite different. How does that fit into the 'thermodynamic view' of the photoelectric effect?

Comment: @JimmyJames An LED is not in thermal equilibrium at all. Also, of course temperature (when it's even applicable) doesn't determine the power output -- you can put a solar panel in the shade and it'll do worse even though the Sun's temperature doesn't change when you do this. It only determines the maximum possible efficiency, i.e. how much work you can get out of the energy you do capture.

Comment: @knzhou "An LED is not in thermal equilibrium at all." How does that fit into the thermodynamic view of the photoelectric effect?  Can you point to a reference that describes this?  I made a few searches and I can't find much of anything that mentions both and what I do find doesn't seem to bolster this assertion.

Comment: @JimmyJames Not all light comes from objects at thermal equilibrium. If a firefly flashes the same color as the Sun, that doesn't mean the firefly is at 6000 K.  Lasers can make bright light but they don't really have a temperature -- and if you try to artifically assign a temperature, it'll be _negative_, not large and positive. You won't find sources saying this because this is just one of those things that goes without saying. For similar reasons, you will not see sources say whether or not Intel CPUs are strongly typed programming languages, because the question doesn't parse.

Comment: @knzhou I'm having trouble squaring the last comment (which makes sense to me) with your first comment (which does not.)

Comment: @JimmyJames The usual Carnot bound on efficiency makes sense if you're working between two reservoirs at thermal equilibrium. For solar panels, this is roughly the Sun's surface temperature and room temperature. If you point the panel at an empty room instead, the two temperatures are room temperature and room temperature, so the maximum efficiency is zero.

Comment: On one hand you are saying lasers have no temperature but I know they can produce current in a solar panel. On the other hand you are saying that solar panels work because there's a temperature difference between the panel and the surface of the sun.  I don't see how those two ideas are compatible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which makes me wonder: why isn't it practicable to generate
>   electricity by drawing thermal energy from the environment?

You can do it but it may not be practicable because you will always need to find an even lower temperature environment to reject some heat to and the efficiency would probably be very low. There will always be the need to reject some heat to a lower temperature environment in order to produce net work in a cycle. The Kelvin Planck statement of the second law, essentially says:

*It is impossible for any device that operates on a cycle to receive heat from a single reservoir and produce a net amount of work.*

The left most diagram below shows a violation of the Kelvin Planck statement. Although it is possible for a single process within a cycle to extract heat and produce work, such as the reversible isothermal expansion of a Carnot heat engine cycle, it is not possible as the sole result of a thermodynamic cycle. You will always need a lower temperature environment to reject some heat.

Regarding efficiency, let's say you take heat from outdoors on a hot summer day of 100 F (311 K) to operate your heat engine and reject heat indoors at say 70 F (294 K). The maximum (Carnot) efficiency of your engine will be $1-\frac{T_L}{T_H}$ or about 5%.

> Do the laws of physics prevent the heat that heat pumps deliver from
>   being used for electricity generation by whatever means (e.g. steam
>   turbine)?

No, but I agree with @Andrew Steane answer that the best you can do is break even by using the work output of a perfect heat engine to provide the needed work input to operate a perfect heat pump.

The right two diagrams shows what Andrew describes as a perfect heat pump (a Carnot heat pump) driving a perfect heat engine (a Carnot heat engine). The heat delivered to the high temperature reservoir by the heat pump is taken by the heat engine to produce work output rejecting some heat to the low temperature reservoir. The heat pump then takes that rejected heat from the low temperature reservoir and uses the work output of the heat engine as its work input required to deliver heat to the high temperature reservoir.

As Andrew stated the best that can be done (for a Carnot heat engine and Carnot heat pump) is for the electrical work produced by the heat engine to equal the electrical work required to operate the heat pump, for a net work of zero. And this can only occur if there is no overall (systems plus surroundings) increase in entropy, which is the case here for the following reasons.

Since both the heat pump and engine are operating in a cycle, the initial and final entropy (initial and final states of the systems) have to be the same, for total entropy changes of each system equal to zero.

The total entropy change of the high temperature reservoir is zero since the heat delivered to it by the heat pump equals the heat taken from it by the heat engine, each divided by the same temperature.

Likewise the total entropy change of the low temperature reservoir is zero since the heat extracted from it by the heat pump equals the heat rejected to it by the heat engine, each divided by the same temperature.

The net result is that the total entropy change of the systems plus surroundings is zero, which can only occur for reversible processes. For all real processes there will be an increase in total entropy. That, in turn, would mean less efficiency for both the heat pump and heat engine, i.e., less work output for the heat engine for the same heat input from the high temperature environment,  and more work input needed for the heat pump to transfer the same amount of heat to the high temperature environment.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: This might not be relevant to the scope of the question but if you consider a e.g. bore-hole to be 'part of the environment, wouldn't that be usable heat sink to dump the heat to?

Comment: @Jimmy James What’s a bore hole?

Comment: Sorry it's one actually one word: [borehole](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Principles-of-direct-geothermal-heating-and-cooling-borehole-not-to-scale-The-ground_fig1_260554619)

Comment: Still don’t know what it is

Comment: The link with the picture and paragraph and explanation didn't help?  Here's and article titled: [What is a Grouted, Geothermal Borehole?](https://www.geoexchange.org/grouted-geothermal-borehole/).  Beyond that, I'm not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: I see it now. Do you know the max temperature vs depth is a borehole?

Comment: @JimmyJames According to Wikipedia, for most of the world the increase in temperature between the surface of the earth and below the surface is between 25 - 30 C per kilometer depth.  Assuming a typical temperature at the surface of 25 C this means the temperature is between 50 - 55 C per kilometer, or 323-328 K. The maximum possible heat engine efficiency operating between these temperatures would be 7.7%-9.1%. For this to be practical depths much greater than 1 km are needed. I'm not sure this technology is yet proven, but I admit not knowing whether or not it has. Thanks for your input. Bob

Comment: While drilling down to pick up heat is something that could be done, what geothermal boreholes for residential purpose are for using the relatively constant temperature (around 10C, AIUI) of the upper crust for heat pumps. In the winter you can then pull the heat from it and in the summer you can dump heat to it. I've often wondered if you could run something like a [Sterling engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_engine) off of the heat from e.g. a blacktop parking lot.  I'm sure there are practical barriers otherwise someone would be doing it.

Comment: While pulling heat from a pothole may be practical simply for residential heating purposes using it to efficiently generate electrical power is a different matter. The depths needed would require considerable investment

Comment: I think you are missing my point.  The heat is coming from the sun.  The sink is the crust.

Comment: @JimmyJames Sorry, my last comment was actually a continuation of my thinking before seeing your latest comment.

Answer (score 4):

This is all about entropy and the difference between heat and work. Electrical power is a form of work. To get work output using heat transfer, the best one can do is such that there is no net change in entropy of the system and its surroundings. So you run a reversible heat engine (power stations in practice do their best to get close to this ideal case). In such a heat engine, the entropy drawn out of the hot side $\Delta S_1 = Q_1/T_1$ is equal to the entropy delivered to the cold side $\Delta S_2 = Q_2/T_2$ so the heats exchanged are in the ratio
$$
\frac{Q_1}{Q_2} = \frac{T_1}{T_2}
$$
The work obtained, which you can consider the electrical energy generated, is
$$
W = Q_1 - Q_2
$$
So the efficiency, measured as work out per amount of heat supplied, is
$$
\frac{W}{Q_1} = 1 - \frac{Q_1}{Q_2} = 1 - \frac{T_1}{T_2} .
$$
This is all completely standard thermodynamics of heat engines. Your heat pump works by the same principle. In the heat pump, $Q_1$ is the heat delivered to the hotter place, and $W$ is the work supplied in order to make this possible. Overall, therefore, if you use a perfect heat pump to drive a perfect heat engine, then the net ratio of total electrical energy out to work energy supplied is $1$. You just break even and get no overall benefit. In practice, owing to imperfection such as friction and heat conduction, one won't achieve unit efficiency so instead there is a net loss of organised energy and a generation of heat and entropy.

Comment: In a nut shell, the 2nd law of thermodynamics makes such power plants impossible, right?

Comment: @Greendrake Yes; exactly right. The 2nd law wins again.